# Best practice way for linking object attributes to class or object

Tags: python, metaclass

I am looking for a reliable and pythonic way of giving class attributes of a certain type a back-reference to the class they are connected to.

i.e. if there is class definition like the one below, I want to give `SomeAttribute()` a reference back to the `SomeClass` type object.

```python
class SomeClass(object):
    attribute = SomeAttribute()
```

Currently I have an implementation that relies on a manual method call after creating a class with this kind of attributes. (Example below). The problem with the current approach is that a lot of code needs to check if the reference class has already been populated to the attributes whenever they are accessed.

One solution would be to require that the class is initialized, in which case the code from `bind_attributes` could be placed into the `__init__` method. However that obviously requires instantiating the class even if an instance is not otherwise needed. I am sure a better solution could be implemented using metaclasses, but I do not know how a pythonic implementation using a metaclass would look.

```python
import inspect

class Attribute(object):
    def __init__(self, *params):
        self._params = params
        self._definition_class = None

    def bind(self, definition_class):
        self._definition_class = definition_class

    def __call__(self):
        return self._definition_class.separator.join(self._params)


class Definition(object):
    separator = ', '

    publications = Attribute('Books', 'Magazines')
    clothes = Attribute('Shoes', 'Gloves', 'Hats')

    @classmethod
    def bind_attributes(cls):
        for name, attribute in inspect.getmembers(cls, lambda m: isinstance(m, Attribute)):
            attribute.bind(cls)


>>> Definition.bind_attributes()
>>> Definition.publications()
'Books, Magazines'
>>> Definition.clothes()
'Shoes, Gloves, Hats'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a metaclass.  For example:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, members):
        cls = type.__new__(mcls, name, bases, members)
        for m in members.values():
            if isinstance(m, SomeAttribute):
                m.bound_cls = cls
        return cls
```

Now of course one downside is this functionality is tied to the class rather than the attribute, so every class you need this functionality with has to use the metaclass:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyMeta

    attribute = SomeAttribute()
```

Comment: What if I were to inherit from a class, e.g. `class OtherClass(SomeClass): second_attribute = SomeAttribute()`. Would I also have to set `__metaclass__` in the inherited class?

Comment: It will work fine with subclasses; they will automatically inhert their base class's metaclass.  One thing to look out for is that the attributes defined on the base class will still be bound to the base class.  If you want subclasses to have the same attributes but bound specifically to the subclass you'd have to either explicitly redefine those attributes on the subclass, or do something a bit trickier in the metaclass to make copies of the attributes to each subclass.  That could be done too but I'm not sure if it's needed?

Comment: It works for me as long as those attributes that belong to the subclass are bound to the class they are declared in. That seems to be the case as far as I can see. Thanks! (btw. I think it should be `members.values()` in your example)

Comment: `for m in members` _is_ wrong -- `members` is a dictionary, so `m` will be iterated through its keys not values. @lyschoening: You shouldn't accept answers with bugs until they're fixed.

Comment: @lyschoening I'd say it was a good call to accept it if it helped you solve the problem, and that inconsequential bugs that are unrelated to the semantic content of the solution should play no role in voting or acceptances. Mere mistakes of syntax should be totally ignored in cases like this, especially in exactly this case where it was *obviously* just due to a knowledgeable and experienced person writing the code very quickly, and would have been easily rectified by anyone familiar enough with Python to ask or understand the question or answer.